# Find method level custom annotation in a Spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

All I wanted to find out was "all the class/methods in [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) beans which are annotated as @Versioned".

I created my custom annotation as,

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Versioned {
    .....
}
```

This annotation **works perfectly** when I use Java reflection to find methods as:

```
for(Method m: obj.getClass().getMethods()){
    if(m.isAnnotationPresent(Versioned.class)){
        .... // Do something
    }
```

But it does not work when I access Spring beans and try similar check:

```
public class VersionScanner implements ApplicationContextAware{
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext){
        for(String beanName: applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()){
            for(Method m: applicationContext.getBean(beanName).getClass().getDeclaredMethods()){
                if(m.isAnnotationPresent(Versioned.class){
                    // This is not WORKING as expected for any beans with method annotated
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, this code does find other annotations such as @RequestMapping. I am not sure what I am doing wrong with my custom annotation.

Comment: Is the bean proxied?

Comment: I wanted to say No. But SOF need minimum 10 characters :-)

Comment: Ok, please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Methods of what class type are you applying the _@Versioned_ annotation to?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis see this package https://github.com/kamoor/spring-versioned/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kamoor/version/VersionScanner.java

Comment: @Angad, I just created a simple hello world "Service", posted code above. Thank you

Comment: @kamoor are you applying the _@Versioned_ annotation on an interface as opposed to its implementation? I do not see any hello world "Service" code above.

Comment: @Angad There are no interfaces https://github.com/kamoor/spring-versioned/tree/master/src/main/java/com/kamoor

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Going through your code, I figured out that you are using Spring AOP with CGLIB Proxying. Due to which your classes (which have methods annotated with `@Versioned` ) are being proxied.

**I have tested this solution with your code base.**

Use the following code, and it should resolve your issue. Look for more options below the code snippet:

```
@Configuration
public class VersionScanner implements ApplicationContextAware {

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {

        for (String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            Object obj = applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
            /*
             * As you are using AOP check for AOP proxying. If you are proxying with Spring CGLIB (not via Spring AOP)
             * Use org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Proxy#isProxyClass to detect proxy If you are proxying using JDK
             * Proxy use java.lang.reflect.Proxy#isProxyClass
             */
            Class<?> objClz = obj.getClass();
            if (org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.isAopProxy(obj)) {

                objClz = org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.getTargetClass(obj);
            }

            for (Method m : objClz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Versioned.class)) {
                    //Should give you expected results
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To detect a proxy class:

- For Spring AOP proxy using any proxying mechanism use `org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils#isAoPProxy`
- If you are proxying with Spring CGLIB (not via Spring AOP), use  `org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Proxy#isProxyClass`
- If you are proxying using JDK Proxy, use `java.lang.reflect.Proxy#isProxyClass`

I have just written one `if` condition which is sufficient in your case; but in case multiple proxying utilities are used, multiple `if-else` conditions will have to be written based on the information above.

Comment: Just a side note. Those if conditions are not required. The AopUtils.getTargetClass () method resolves all that for you.

Comment: You are right but If conditions required to test for different types of proxies as mentioned in the later part of the answer...

According to Spring docs AopUtils#getTargetClass:
`Determine the target class of the given bean instance which might be an AOP proxy.
Returns the target class for an AOP proxy and the plain class else.
`

Comment: Yes and the utility method returns the required class (target or not) based on what you pass. Spring Aop proxies are nothing but either of jdk or cglib proxies.

Comment: The Utility Method will return required class only if it is AOP proxy. So basically it has to be either jdk or cglib proxy AS WELL as proxy created by Spring AOP.

For Example in the given code test for bean named "server" it is proxied by spring using CGLIB. AopUtils.getTargetClass does not resolve the target class for this as it is not a AOP Proxy.

Comment: If its a CGLIB proxy you do not need to resolve any target class. You can straight away invoke a getClass() on the bean and thereon a getDeclaredMethods() to get all methods without having to lose the method annotation information. The Util method returns the class as it is if it is not an AOP proxy. I'll leave the discussion at this point.

Comment: @Angad We can go on about specific implementations of each proxying mechanism. Trying to keep the solution generic enough based on all the proxying mechanisms available on code's class path. Spring AOP Utils just take care of on Spring AOP proxies as stated by Spring documentation and as you may have already realized by your tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68784/discussion-between-owaism-and-angad).

Answer (score 9):

`applicationContext.getBean(beanName).getClass()` gives you the proxied class that Spring creates around your target class.

What you want is to get hold of the target class, if any, from your Spring bean.

Spring provides a nice utility class for resolving this called AopUtils.class.

Below is how you would use it:

```
for(String beanName: applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()){
    Method[] methods = AopUtils.getTargetClass(applicationContext.getBean(beanName)).getDeclaredMethods();

    for(Method m: methods){
        if(m.isAnnotationPresent(Versioned.class){
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you will have to import the `spring-aop` [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) dependency to get hold of the AopUtils class:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {

    for (String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        Object obj = applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
        Class<?> objClz = obj.getClass();
        if (org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.isAopProxy(obj)) {
            objClz = org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.getTargetClass(obj);
        }

        for (Method m : objClz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Transactional.class)) {
                Transactional transactional = m.getAnnotation(Transactional.class);
                Class<? extends Throwable>[] value = transactional.rollbackFor();
                if (value == null){
                   // help !!!
                    // If value is null, I want to set a value for him like Exception.class How can I modify it?
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```